# Arrange custom sized UILabels Under Equally Sized UIImages all by UIStackView

Tags: swift, uiimage, uilabel, uistackview

I want to arrange variably sized UILabels under equally sized UIImages all by UIStackView. But I end up with scaled down font or text wrapped in two lines. See the images below to get the idea.

[**Actual Issue**] Moreover, the only time it works as expected is when I make the container large enough. My aim is to achieve this within 60% of the screen width, starting from iphone 5 and above.

What I want to achieve:

[image: What I want to achieve]

But I end up with either this result:

[image: But I end up with either this result]

Or this:

[image: Or this]

Structured like this

[image: Structured like this]

NOTE: All UI made with stacks inside stacks. All images and labels have their own stack and then wrapped in subsequent stacks to align them vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Can you show the constraints for the container view ?

Comment: No manual constraints, only stacks inside stacks. Outer most stack is aligned in the middle of the screen for testing purposes.

Comment: Did you play around with auto shrink: fixed font size, and content hugging priority for the label ?

Comment: Yes, second image is the result when I apply auto shrink (I also tried aspect ratio but no success). Hugging/Resistance could not produce desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See constraints relations and views hierarchy on screenshot below. `UILabel` is centered horizontally to `UIImageView`. And has vertical space with `UIImageView` Also `UILabel` is not in `UIStackView` hierarchy.

[image]

UPDATE: Put both UIImageView and UILabel in container (UIView). And then in UIStackView, in case outer stack is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, by placing labels outside of stack. But my limitation is to keep the labels inside the stack, they will always fall under a stack by one way or another, being part of a hierarchy of outer stacks. Is it possible?

Comment: Put bot  `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in container (`UIView`). And then in `UIStackView`.  If I have a time, I provide you an example

Comment: Let me try and I shall confirm.

Comment: Hey, @igor-kotkovets, accept the post edit and I accept your answer.

Comment: Thnaks for your time Igor, it was great help.